# Laravel Nova. Using Image field, is it possible to make "Download" link appear on "update/edit" views?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

"Download" link like that appears only on images on view page. Is it possible to also get it on "update/edit" page?

It seems to be impossible using out of the box Nova field methods.
Is making a custom tool the proper way to achieve this?

[image: the link]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it.

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    $href = $this->modelsHref; // Or however you want to build the link

    return [
          Text::make('Download Link')->asHtml(function () use ($href) {
                return '<a href="'.$href.'"><i class="icon"></i> Download</a>';
            })->onlyOnForms(),
    ];
}
```

Comment: My problem is I need it to look same/similar as to how it looks on view page, meaning right below the image in the same field line.

Comment: Not sure how to do that sorry :(

Comment: Quick thought added based on your comment

Comment: KK, I will remove it. Hope you find a solution to your problem!